# How to import CAD drawings into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import, area, dxf, cad

I have a dxf with a polygon. This polygon has an area of 680279.678 m² in Autocad.
When i import it into QGIS and calculate the area in the field calculator with area($geometry) i get 680281.25
I think the problem has something to do with the way things are drawn in CAD.
In this example the polygon has cooordinates which matches the CRS with EPSG 8395.
In pure Autocad you can not choose a CRS, this seems to be limited to programs like Map3 and Civil3D so in the example my guess is that the coordinates are in EPS8395 but in reality the polygon is drawn without a CRS so that when i import the dxf and assign it to EPSG8395 i do the wrong thing because it is not really 8395 and so the geometry is slightly changed and i get a different area.
Maybe i am wrong and the source of the error is something different.
When i use the AnotherDXFImporter plugin i get 680295.99 m² which is even more off than the build in importer.
When the areas do not match than probably the coordinates will not match too.
At the moment i have no clue what the right worklow might be to get the polygon to be at the same place and with the same size as in CAD.

Comment: CAD returns planimetric areas, while QGIS takes the geoid into account. By using `area($geometry)` you can force QGIS to measure planimetric, too. Also, depending on how you import your data and whether there are circle segments within the polygon, this can be another source if discrepancies.

Comment: i exported the polygon from QGIS back to dxf and put into the original polygon dwg and they are slightly different in some parts. You are right, it has something to do with the curves. The Qgis Polyline has more points in the curved areas. It seems there were points added by the dxfimporter to simulate a curve where none was in the original polygon. This happens at some places along the polygon, sometimes it adds and sometimes it subtracts area compared to the original poylgon and in the end it ends up as slightly more than the original. Thx @Erik

Comment: i rechecked and found that no points were added but that it seems the qgis polyline is curved a bit different than the original one.

Comment: i think the problem is that the parts of the polygon that are arcs in cad are converted to lines at a certain point. Maybe at the import or when using the "Lines to Polygons" Tool

Comment: It is important, how you import the data into QGIS. Drag & drop leads to conversion of arcs to line segments, while "Project - Import/Export - Import from DXF/DWG" preserves the arcs. Some tools also change arcs to linesegments, but you can e.g. omit the `lines to polygons` tool by exporting hatches instead of lines from CAD.

Comment: Ok, i checked and i have curves after import but still the slight difference compared to the dwg/dxf. I have no clue where the error is. In this case the difference is small but what if you have a long countryborder of several thousand kilometers than it adds up. Thanks for help so far. @Erik

Comment: I think the problem might be that the imported data from CAD uses the coordinates of a crs but since the lines are drawn in pure Autocad which knows nothing about crs systems it is not really drawn in a crs but only uses the coordinates of it. So if i import data an give it the crs i probably distort it and this leads to the error. I probably have to import the data without giving it a crs or i have to make a dummy crs which changes absolutely nothing of the data. I have the impression i can not really use a gis program when the CAD data was not produced with a program that uses crs systems.

Comment: Nope, sorry (unless you're talking about things with a magnitude of the Nordstream 2 pipeline e.g.).